# Is this sentence in the passive voice?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, tenses, passive-voice

- *An estimated 5000 primates are kept as pets in the UK.*

is this sentence in the passive voice? If yes, how do I write it in active voice.

Is this a present passive voice? Is there such thing?

i have another question, the word 'as' here, is it a preposition or an adverb? if its an adverb, what type is it? – olivia just now   Edit   Delete

Comment: To write the sentence in the active voice, you have to invent an agent, missing from the original: people, owners, folks?

Comment: (1) Yes // (2) In the UK, individuals keep an estimated 5000 primates as pets.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: i have another question, the word 'as' here, is it a preposition or an adverb? if its an adverb, what type is it?

Comment: **Why** would you want to turn this sentence into an active-voice one? A vague subject, such as *people* or *individuals* doesn't really add anything useful to the sentence.

Comment: It's a preposition. The dictionary says "used to refer to the function or character that someone or something has". The adverb form is in comparisons, e.g. "as fast as you can" or "as sweet as honey"